# Merged two arrays with replcaing values

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays.

```
$mainarray = array( 123456 => array("id" => 123456,"data_reference_id" => 456788,"event_type_id" => 162,"event_handle" => 'Work Order #456788 Outgoing Email to <strong>Mr Maan</strong> by <strong>System</strong>',"updated_by"=> 801) );


$emailarray = array( 123456 => array("id" => 123456,"data_reference_id" => 456788,"event_type_id" => 162,"event_handle" => 'Work Order #456788 Outgoing Email to <strong>1 resident</strong> by <strong>System</strong>',"updated_by" =>'') );
```

If I used `array_merge` it simply appends `$emailarray` to `$mainarray`.

```
$finalarray = array_merge( $emailarray, $mainarray );
```

If I used `+` operator it gives first array ( left array to + operator).

Expected result should be

```
$finalarray = array( 123456 => array("id" => 123456,"data_reference_id" => 456788,"event_type_id" => 162,"event_handle" => 'Work Order #456788 Outgoing Email to <strong>1 resident</strong> by <strong>System</strong>',"updated_by"=> 801) );
```

Is there any way to get this?

Comment: which array gets the priority? you could just use a `foreach` for that

Answer (score 0):

This may somewhat give you what you want:

```
$finalarray =  array_unique(array_merge($mainarray,$emailarray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this way it will help you get the expected results, use to [array_unique](http://php.net/en/array_unique)

```
$finalarray = array_unique(array_merge($mainarray,$emailarray), SORT_NUMERIC );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($finalarray);
echo '</pre>';
```